# Slow running query with subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that takes several minutes to run. It is actually part of a larger query, but this part seems to be the bottleneck. I has an inner select that is probably the culprit.

I am looking for additional of indexes or other rearrangement to speed it up. I am thinking perhaps putting that subselect into a temporary table, except that it uses data from the outer query in the where clause, so that won't work.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT principalid, count(*) AS CRs_used FROM
(
    SELECT crMan.principalid, crMan.repid, MIN(crMan.daterequest) as FirstContactDate
    FROM contactrequest crMan
    INNER JOIN principal p
        ON crMan.principalid = p.userid
    WHERE
        initiatedby = 2
        AND status <> 'C'
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
             SELECT *
             FROM contactrequest crRep
             WHERE crMan.principalid = crRep.principalid
                 AND crMan.repid = crRep.repid
                 AND initiatedby = 1
                 AND status <> 'C'
                 AND crRep.daterequest < crMan.daterequest
         )
    GROUP BY userid, crMan.principalid, crMan.repid) AS ContactRequestsThatCount GROUP BY principalid;
```

Schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `principal` (
  `operid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `userid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `targetcustomer` varchar(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `targetcustomer_stemmed` varchar(10000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `productline` varchar(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `productline_stemmed` varchar(10000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `salesopportunity` varchar(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `salesopportunity_stemmed` varchar(10000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `annualsales` decimal(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketingassistance` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trainingprovided` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclusiveterritories` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `repagency` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `made_in_usa` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `established_line` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `contactrequest` (
  `operid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `contactrequestid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `repid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `principalid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `initiatedby` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `response` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `reasonid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `daterequest` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `dateresponse` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `archivebypri` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `archivebyrep` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contactrequestid`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_repid_request` (`repid`,`daterequest`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_principalid_request` (`principalid`,`daterequest`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=851354 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is the EXPLAIN output:

[image]

EDIT:

The purpose of the query is as follows; the contactrequest table contains records of contacts between two members of our website, indicated as principals and reps. Either side can initiate the request; initiatedby = 1 means the rep initiated; initiatedby = 2 means principal initiated. There can be multiple such records between every pair of principa and reps.

The query counts the number of contacts from principals to reps but where there is not contact from a rep to a principal with an earlier timestamp. Also, rows with status = 'C' are ignored.

The indexes suggested in the answers below are already partly included. The indexes for status and initiatedby are not because according to SQL documentation indexes with low cardinality should not be used. initiatedby only has values in (1, 2), and status in ('C','N',''). So very low cardinality.

EDIT 2:

After looking at the original query and the answers, this question is not making sense and I am thinking the SQL has been changed. The evidence for this is that the suggestion from -- has something in it that could not be there unless is was in the original query. So I am going to modify the original query back to what I think it should have been.

The problem is that part of the last line is not visible in the rendered question, but when you try to edit, the proper text is in fact there. I am going to try to get it so you can see it in the formatted code.

EDIT 3:

Revised schema with addition on suggested index:

```
CREATE TABLE `contactrequest` (
  `operid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `contactrequestid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `repid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `principalid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `initiatedby` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `response` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `reasonid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `daterequest` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `dateresponse` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `archivebypri` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `archivebyrep` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contactrequestid`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_repid_request` (`repid`,`daterequest`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_principalid_request` (`principalid`,`daterequest`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_initiatedby` (`initiatedby`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_status` (`status`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_daterequest` (`daterequest`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_dateresponse` (`dateresponse`),
  KEY `ix_contactrequest_temp` (`repid`,`initiatedby`,`status`,`daterequest`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=858323 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In addition to the suggested index, I added several of the columns as indices also. It turns out that the improved query speed does not occur with just the suggested index, but by adding each of the separate ones more improvement is gained. I don't understand this, because I would think the indexes are now redundant.

NOTE: dateresponse was added recently for other purposes, but not to support this query

Comment: Qualify your column names so it is clear what the query is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by simplifying the query:

```
SELECT principalid, COUNT(DISTINCT userid, repid) AS CRs_used
FROM contactrequest crMan INNER JOIN
     principal p
     ON crMan.principalid = p.userid
WHERE initiatedby = 2 AND
      status <> 'C' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM contactrequest crRep
                   WHERE crMan.principalid = crRep.principalid AND
                         crMan.repid = crRep.repid AND
                         initiatedby = 1 AND
                         status <> 'C' AND
                         crRep.daterequest < crMan.daterequest
                )
GROUP BY principalid;
```

You want an index on `contactrequest(repid, initiatedby, status, daterequest)`.

With more information about the query and what it is supposed to be doing, there might be more you can do.

Comment: The suggested query gives 10658 rows as does the original query. I have run both queries a few times. In those tests the suggested query runs in about 5 minutes; the original query runs in about 3 minutes. So we may just have to live with it.

Comment: @JeffreySimon . . . Do you have the suggested index?

Comment: I edited the original comment to explain about the indexes.

Comment: @JeffreySimon . . . This answer recommends an index.  If you want performance, I suggest you create it.

Comment: I decided to add the suggested index to see what happens. My thinking was that that index was redundant because of other indices already present. See the original question for an edit showing the updated schema. Running my original query rather than the simplified one but with the additional index took the runtime of the query from 2:21 (minutes:seconds) down to 1:32.  However, the simplified query does sometimes take the run time down to about 1:00. Other times there is no gain. Yet simplicity is better, so I will adopt the suggested query and index for now, and accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a subquery here, `select case` should be able to handle this. if criteria matches on your `not exists` clause, setting the `date` to maximum which is `'9999-12-31'` will not be a candidate in your `min()` function

```
SELECT principalid, count(*) AS CRs_used FROM
    (
        SELECT crMan.principalid, crMan.repid
            , min(case when crMan.principalid = p.principalid 
                        and initiatedby = 1
                        and status <> 'C'                       
                    then '9999-12-31' 
                    when initiatedby = 2 and status <> 'C'
                    then crMan.daterequest
                    else crMan.daterequest end)
                 as FirstContactDate
        FROM contactrequest crMan
        INNER JOIN principal p
            ON crMan.principalid = p.userid  
        WHERE initiatedby = 2 AND status <> 'C'
        GROUP BY userid, crMan.principalid, crMan.repid) AS ContactRequestsThatCount
```

Comment: The original query returns 10658 rows. This suggestion returns 1 row. It is not correct.

Comment: See the edit in the question above for explanation of the purpose of the query.